# PHP/Txt - How to save into session/load from session

Tags: php, forms, session, text

This is quite a long-winded question as im completely lost!

The concept: User inputs a text file they wish to write to, upon submitting they are sent to a page where users can create shapes and submit them to the text file, this data is then used to work out the shapes area, colour that was selected etc...

Issue is how do i write to a text file that is in the session?

This is what i have on the home page:

```
<?php

// This line starts the session

session_start();

//The below calls the file

$txtFile = $_POST['submittedTxtFile']; 
$_SESSION['submittedTxtFile']= $txtFile;
$file = fopen($txtFile, "r") or exit("That file does not exist");

include_once 'classShapeCollection.php';

//Creates the shapecollection
$shapes = new ShapeCollection();

//These lines get the called file, unserialize the $shapes and serialize them again before entering them into the session.

$buffer = fgets($file);

//Checking if there are any contents in the file

if($buffer)

    {
    $shapes = unserialize($buffer); //unserialize takes Text and turns it into an object
    $_SESSION['serial']= serialize($shapes); //Serialize takes the objects and converts them into Text
    }
    else //if there is nothing in the file, the session serialises the new ShapeCollection
    {
    $_SESSION['serial']= serialize($shapes);
    }

// Closes the called file
fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: You can do this in one line `$txtFile = $_POST['submittedTxtFile'] = $_SESSION['submittedTxtFile'];` (*chaining method*) then just use what you're using now `$file = fopen($txtFile, "r")...` you can then get rid of `$txtFile = $_POST['submittedTxtFile']; 
$_SESSION['submittedTxtFile']= $txtFile;`

Comment: `file_put_contents($txtfile, serialize($whatever))`. it's not rocketscience...

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry could you elaborate as an answer because im quite new to this so unsure on what you want me to change

Comment: There is an error also with your `$file = fopen($txtFile, "r")` where `r` is read-only. You need to use `w` or `w+` as stated below. Plus, the file in question; that will depend which format you want to use. Sidenote: If you want to ADD to a file, you need to use either the `a` or `a+` switch.

Comment: But im not writing anything on that page, just reading to use snippets like counting how many shapes currently exist... but when i try adding a new shape i get this That file does not exist

Comment: Ok, I get it now. You wrote in your question: *"User inputs a text file they wish to write to"* --- then the user would need to know the exact filename, right? Do they know the exact filename? @user3365872 But now, your question also states *"Issue is how do i write to a text file that is in the session?"* So now you want to "write" to a file.

Comment: yes they would do, then once they submit that.. it creates a session on the homepage it just needs to read for the count, then theres a series of shapes.. each one is img redirecting to another page where theres a form to insert the shapes dimensions and select a colour -- that insert shape page is where it then needs to write to the file

Comment: I have something I can show you (*in an answer*) but I won't be able to further help (it will be an as-is code), however you can base yourself on it. @user3365872 I have to tend to other things right now. Let me know if you're interested.

Comment: You're welcome (*coming right up*). Sidenote: I'm not in this for the (possible) points, I'm in this to possibly help. Some on SO (*not aimed at you*) seem to get the wrong impression when it comes to actually wanting to help people.  @user3365872

Comment: I take it my answer didn't help? Given your new question. @user3365872

Comment: @Fred-ii- i've just done it differently, but now im trying to figure out whether - if someone wants to create their own database of entries they have the option to create a empty text file and upload to server, then use that instead of shapeStorage.txt

Answer (score 0):

Opening the file as "r" means read only you should open it as write

```
fopen($txtFile, 'r+')
```

Or replace `'r+'` with `'w+'` if you want file to be truncated when opened

Answer (score 0):

After closing the file handler, use file_put_contents() function to update the file. Like this:

```
fclose($file);
file_put_contents($txtfile, $_SESSION['serial']);
```

Make sure the file is writable.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

The following will write to a file called `TEST.txt` taken from the `$write_session = "TEST";` session variable.

Base yourself on it, am sure you will get it to work the way you want it to, but that's basically how it will work.

```
<?php
session_start();

$_POST['submittedTxtFile'] = "file.txt"; // generic filename
$txtFile = $_POST['submittedTxtFile'];
$_SESSION['submittedTxtFile']= $txtFile;
$write_session = "TEST";

$_SESSION['write_session_write'] = $write_session;

$file = fopen($txtFile, "r") or exit("That file does not exist");

echo $_SESSION['submittedTxtFile'];

$file2 = $_SESSION['write_session_write'] . ".txt";
file_put_contents($file2, $write_session);
```